# Delphi TWebBrowser specify port in url

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using Delphi XE2 and the `TWebBrowser` component.

I have a server listening on port 8000. I can load my browser and specify the port in the url and get the correct response from my server using `http://localhost:8000`.

When I try to pass the same url to the `TWebBrowser` component, it seems to ignore the port number altogether and simply says "document not found" (and does not even connect to the server).

Normally, you can embed the port number in the url (if it is not port 80), but I seem unable to do this with the `TWebBrowser` component, so `C1.Navigate('localhost:8000')` does not work.

Is there any way I can use the `TWebBrowser` component with a non-standard port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if you include the protocol in the URL that you pass to `Navigate`:

```
C1.Navigate('http://localhost:8000/');
```

Comment: @DaveLister Protocol should be required everywhere. It's typically standard behavior of modern web browsers to automatically add (yet hide) the protocol from the users, but behind the scenes it's still there. I mean, it's no surprise that it doesn't support a URL without protocol.

Comment: @JerryDodge right, because many protocols don't even have a port component in their respective URL schemas. That is something that only applies to IP-based protocols, including HTTP/S